# formatting timestamp in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save a timestamp every time an entity is created or updated.

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_At")
private Date createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;
```

The problem is this saves the timestamp in the unix time format. I want it to be saved in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

I have tried doing this using the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations but for some reason the methods are not called when the entity is created/updated.

Is there any other way of controlling the format?
Note: I'm not sure if it is relevant but I'm using the Spring framework

Answer (score 0):

You store your data in DB. DB stores date fields always as its internal format such as miliseconds from EPOC or something like this. It is responsibility of a client to read it and display it in any format it wants to. Once you read your Date field back in java you can format your Date in any way you want before displaying it. The same goes for whatever DB viewer you use. You can usually configure it to display your Date fields in DB in any format you want but internally in DB it will stilled be stored in DB internal format.